# PHP Search query result ORDER BY not working

Tags: php, search, sql-order-by

I have this code to search database. It now works perfectly but i want to change the order of which it displays. Below is my code.

```
if (isset($_GET["mainSearch"])) 
{
  $condition = '';
  $query = explode(" ", $_GET["mainSearch"]);

  foreach ($query as $text) 
  {
      $condition .= "question LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($text)."%' OR ";
  }
  $condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);


  $order = "ORDER BY quiz_id DESC";
  $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE " . $condition;
  $sql_query_count = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM questions WHERE " . $condition . $order;
  $result = $db->query($sql_query);
  $resultCount = $db->querySingle($sql_query_count);

  if ($resultCount > 0)
  {
  if ($result)
  {
      while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
      {
           echo '<div class="quesbox_3">
            <div class="questitle">
                <h2>'.$row["question"].'</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="quesanswer">'.$row["answer"].'</div>
        </div>';
      }
  }
  }
  else
  {
      echo "No results found";
  }
}
```

I want the ORDER of which result show to be from bottom to top. Please how can i add this properly as current code isn't working.

Comment: What is the issue you are getting?

Comment: @urfusion its just not reordering.

Comment: @AlivetoDie astonished myself cause error_reporting is on

Comment: `echo` your query and run that in `phpmyadmin`. see what you get is right or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$order` is in your count query alone. Add to your `$sql_query`

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE " . $condition . ' '. $order;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your putting the order by on the count() query, which doesn't do much really.

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE " . $condition;
  $sql_query_count = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM questions WHERE " . $condition . $order;
```

Try

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE " . $condition. ' '. $order;
  $sql_query_count = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM questions WHERE " . $condition ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give 1 space in this string

```
$order = " ORDER BY quiz_id DESC ";
```

It is not showing you because if you echo your query than it will show like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM questions WHERE question LIKE '%test%'ORDER BY quiz_id DESC
```

You can see in this echo query there is a no space between `ORDER and %test%`

do Like this it will helps you.

Comment: You are right about the spaces but the search results still doesn't reorder. Or even when i add a LIMIT 1 to the $order, It doesn't limit the results.

Answer (score 0):

> Query Space issues. can you try with this query

```
 $sql_query_count = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM questions WHERE " . $condition .' '. $order;
```

Comment: If you would add some comment as to what you've changed and why it helps it would make your answer much more useful.